# parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, php, json

When I add `if(isset($_POST['uplprofimg']))`, I get the error:

```
parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

If I exclude the php if isset post function, the code works perfectly.

So, PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['uplprofimg'])){ //← This  if broke my code >:(
        //Works if I remove the ↑
        if($_FILES['imagefile']['size'] > 5242880){
            $ress = "<div class='error'>Max file size is 5MB</div>";
            echo json_encode(array('response' => false,'ress' => $ress));
        }else{
            $imgtype = pathinfo($_FILES['imagefile']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(!in_array($imgtype,array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif'))){
                $ress = "<div class='error'>Only <b>jpg</b>, <b>jpeg</b>, <b>png</b> and <b>gif</b> files are allowed (".$imgtype.")</div>";
                echo json_encode(array('response' => false,'ress' => $ress));
            }else{
                $newimgname = "/profile_picture/".random_num($length = 8).time().random_num($length = 8).".".$imgtype;
                $newimgnameserv = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$newimgname;
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],$newimgnameserv)){
                    $upuser = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE accinfo SET profilepic = ? WHERE username = ?');
                    $upuser->bind_param('ss',$newimgname,$username);
                    $check = $upuser->execute();
                    if($check == true){
                        echo json_encode(array('response' => true));
                    }else{
                        $ress = "<div class='error'>SQL Error</div>";
                        echo json_encode(array('response' => false,'ress' => $ress));   
                    }
                }else{
                    $ress = "<div class='error'>Couldn't move the file. Please try again later.(".$newimgname.")</div>";
                    echo json_encode(array('response' => false,'ress' => $ress));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and JS:

```
$("#uploadimgform").on("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $("#uploadlistener").html("<img src='/images/load.gif' width='50px' />");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/system/requests.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.response === true){
                $("#bodyfader").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#expandedupl").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#uploadlistener").html("");
            }else{
                $("#uploadlistener").html(data.ress);
                $('#profilepic').css('background', 'url(/images/defaultprof.png)');
                $("#profilepic").css("background-size","cover");
                $("#profilepic").css("background-position","center");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

If I remove the `if(isset($_POST['uplprofimg'])){...}`, the code works. But if I add it there, I get the json error. What is going on?

HTML Form:

```
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" id='uploadimgform' style='display: none;'>
     <input type='file' id='upload' name='imagefile' accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
     <input type='submit' id='uploadconf' name='uplprofimg' />
</form>
```

This is how the form is submitted:

```
$("#upload").change(function(){
    if(this.files[0].size > 5242880){
        $("#uploadlistener").html("<div class='error'>Maximum file size is 5MB.</div>");
        $("#upload").val("");   
    }else{
        $("#uploadimgform").submit();
        readURL(this);
    }
});
```

I have no idea why, but I did this:

```
formData.append('uplprofimg',1);
```

and the code works. Someone can explain this?

Comment: is there a `name="uplprofimg"` in the form? Provide a [mcve]. Also what are you sending if that post index doesn't exist?

Comment: the input type submit has name uplprofimg

Comment: @StevenDropper what is the result of print_r($_POST) ? can you post it as well please ?

Comment: Honestly, I am confused as much as you are. @Steven Dropper

Comment: ...just going to set a bounty...

Comment: @StevenDropper If you found the solution you should add it as an answer

Comment: You were trying to process a JSON that was not correctly built (probably null or empty string). By adding the field `uplprofimg` and with the `if(isset($_POST['uplprofimg']))` you make sure that you build a valid JSON you can later process with your AJAX request.

Comment: I still dont see a difference... the name='uplprofimg' is included as a form data... so...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) to send the submit button value to the server.

The submit element is not added to the entries.

I have not found clear details in the [submit specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#submit-button-state-(type=submit)) or in the [construction of the formData](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-the-form-data-set).

Indeed, when running this snippet we can see that the submit value is not appended to the FormData.

```js
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#myForm'));
for (var p of formData.entries()) {
  console.log(p[0] + " " + p[1]);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="sometext" value="This is submitted" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="someSubmitValue" />
</form>
```

I would suggest you to use a hidden input if you need to send some additional data that is not part of the displayed input elements.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `upload_max_filesize` option in the `php.ini` file.
The default max size is 2M. You need to set a higher value:

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The user is having issues with uplprofimg not being submitted unless he appends it to the FormData